# How to store only a part of an object in ASP.Net session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, memory

I handle a few object that can have references to large DataTable. I'd like to store those objects in session withouth the DataTable because those can be regenerated easily and I'd like to spare some memory.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Thins I've tried :

- Think about it
- Avoid feeling just fine with the first workarround coming to mind since better method could exist
- Admit the limit of my knowledge
- Ask on stackoverflow
- Wish for an interesting discovery

Comment: You can assign null value to Data table specific properties or variable of that objects.

Comment: When to do this to be sure the current process doesn't still have use of the datatable?

Comment: Or what about creating a new class that contains properties for all of those values that you care about and have a constructor that takes in your existing object type, and store that new class instance in the session?

Comment: Do you want to do it automatically for all DataTables? Do you want to do it for specific cases, explicitly? Do you want to use custom attribute to decorate the properties that shouldn't be serialized? Whnat have you tried, What have failed?

Comment: If an attribute does the magic, please let me know.

Comment: @JotaBe : How do you recognize a stackoverflow user? When you can't find your way and ask for directions, he answer "What have you tried?".

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that easy. But i'll explain you a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a general solution to nullify the properties of a class decorated with a custom attribute. For example, you can create this attribute and class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MvcApp
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class NullifyAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    public class PropertyNullifier
    {
        public static T Nullify<T>(T original)
            where T : class
        {
            // Limitations:
            // 1) only works for POCOs with public properties: t.GetProperties()
            // 2) only works for classes with public constructor
            // 3) it's not recursive
            Type t = original.GetType();
            // This looks for all the properties that are not marked with nullified
            List<PropertyInfo> notNullifiedProperties = 
                t.GetProperties() // 1)
                .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (NullifyAttribute), true).Any())
                .ToList();
            // This creates an instance of the object
            T copy = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); // 2)
            // And this copy the non-nullified properties
            foreach (var p in notNullifiedProperties)
            {
                p.SetValue(copy, p.GetValue(original)); // 3) apply recursion to 2nd parameter
            }
            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Note the limitations in the comments!! At least, this doesn't modify the original objects, an makes a shallow copy (copy the references to the reference properties) which is quite fast. The extra limitaiton is the speed. This could be improved in several ways, for example caching the not nullified properties, using Reflection instead of Activator, modify it to only create a copy if there are nullifiable properties. The last improvement it's very easy to implemente. Add this code: `if (notNullifiedProperties.Count == 0) return original;`

Then, before storing the object in Session, nullify its properties an store the nullified copy of this object. This unit test explains how to nullify (you'd store the nullified object in session).

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using MvcApp;

namespace Test.MvcApp
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
        [Nullify]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class PropertyNullifierTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            SampleClass sampleObject = new SampleClass
            {
                Name = "John Smith",
                Age = 22,
            };

            SampleClass nullified = PropertyNullifier.Nullify(sampleObject);

            Assert.IsNull(nullified.Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(sampleObject.Age, nullified.Age);
        }
    }
}
```

However, with this solution you still have to use the nullifier before storing in session.
Another option is to create your own class for storing the session, and change web.config to use it. In this way you can automatically nullify before storing.

This is not a very general solution. So you can make something more complex: create your own custom session state store, and configure web.confgi to use it. Here you have a whole working example: [of this solution](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2007/06/wrapped-inprocsessionstatestore.html). You'd have to modify this sample to use the nullifier class or use it modifying the serialization methods to ignore the custom attribute decorated properties, checking if they are decorated or not (using the correspondign part of my code).

Taking the extra work to make it more or less automatic, and determining if this works, depends on the details of your project.

**Want it much easier?** Well, you're lucky enough. If you change the [Session mode to State Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net), it will automatically use serialization. Then you can use the [standard `NonSerialized` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But this can be dangerous: if you try to store non-serializable objects you'll get an exception.

As you can see there is no optimum solution: just take which best fits you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Interface like following and apply on classes where you want this behavior

```
public interface IClearBeforeSessionStore
{
  public void ClearWhichAreBigger();
} 

public class A : IClearBeforeSessionStore
{
  public DataTable dt {get;set;}
  public string AnyString { get;set;}

  public void ClearWhichAreBigger()
  {
     this.dt = null;
  }
}
```

Store A class object in session like this

```
A objA = new A();
objA.AnyString = "Object A";
objA.dt = new DataTable(); // or any existing one

Session["objA"] = objA.ClearWhichAreBigger();
```

When you get it back from session like following you can access only AnyString property

```
A objA = Session["objA"] as A;
if(objA.AnyString == "Object A" && objA.dt == null)
{
   // yes I am from session !!!!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "copy constructor" to the class that copies all the members apart from the ones you don't want like this:

```
public class BigData
{
  private string _someValue;
  private DataSet _bigDataSet;

  public BigData()
  {
      ...
  }

  public BigData(BigData toBeCloned)
  {
     this._someValue = toBeCloed._someValue;
     // Don't copy _bigDataSet here!
  }
}
```

You could then add to the session like this:

```
session["BigDataWithoutDataSet"] = new BigData(bigDataContainingDataSet);
```